# Calendar Control: Have todays date selected on page load

Tags: asp.net, webforms, calendar

I have a calendar control on a asp .net webform.  In the Pag_Load event I have

```
this.CalendarReportDay.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Which sets the Calendar's Selected Date but todays date is not highlighted on the calendar.

Does anyone know how to get todays date to be selected?

Comment: Just a punt, but do you have a SelectedDayStyle on the calendar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SelectedDate` will set the calendar's date, but that does not mean it will highlight it.

One issue is that `DateTime.Now` includes the time whereas the calendar needs ONLY the date to work as expected, so you can use `DateTime.Today` instead, e.g.

```
myCalendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today
```

To show the date (i.e. to get the calendar to display the correct month and year needed to show the selected date) use `VisibleDate`, e.g.

```
myCalendar.VisibleDate = dateToUse;
```

For more details, have a look at:

http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/how-highlight-day-aspnet-calendar-control-selecteddate-property

Comment: Please note that, as shown above, it's DateTime.Today, NOT DateTime.Now. Otherwise the date will not be selected.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set

```
this.CalendarReportDay.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

The Date property at the end is important, otherwise the time component of DateTime.Now will prevent the selection. Then it gets the applied SelectedDayStyle, f.e.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="CalendarReportDay" runat="server">
   <SelectedDayStyle Font-Size="X-Large" />
</asp:Calendar>
```